# ¿Se puede hacer un for each inverso?

Tags: java, bucle-for, foreach

Buen día tengan todos mi duda es si se puede llegar a realizar un for each inverso y ¿como? ya que necesito imprimir una pila pero al hacerlo lo hace de forma normal como se introducen los datos los imprime y quisiera realizarlo a la inversa, sé que se puede hacer con un for normal pero quisiera saber si se puede llegar a realizar en el for each.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
for (String elementos:pila)
{
    System.out.println(elementos);
}
```

Comment: ¿No te funcionaria usar una cola (Queue) en lugar de una pila?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el tipo de `pila`?

Answer (score 1):

Dale la vuelta al array antes de pasarlo por el foreach y si no cuando lo rellenas hazlo a la inversa, si no prueba con la clases collections parece que tiene una función que cambia el contenido del array

```
public static void main(String[] args) 

{ 

    Integer [] arr = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}; 
    Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(arr)); 

}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, considera revisar [answer], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Cabe mencionar que esto debe ser con un for, ya que con un **foreach** es fundamentalmente imposible porque el bucle frontal se basa en las interfaces Iterable e Iterator, y estas no tienen una noción de iteración inversa.

Y para hacerlo supongamos que tengo el siguiente arreglo:

```
int pila[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
```

La manera normal de imprimirlo como tu lo tienes seria:

```
for (int elementos:pila)
{
    System.out.println(elementos);
}
```

Esto te imprime:

```
10
20
30
40
50
```

La manera invertida de imprimirlo seria:

```
for(int contador=pila.length-1; contador>=0; contador--)
{
    System.out.println(pila[contador]);
}
```

Esto te imprime:

```
50
40
30
20
10
```

Igualamos la variable **contador** a la longitud de la `pila-1`, le damos la condición de **contador mayor o igual a 0** y  hacemos un `contador--`.

Aquí te dejo mi ejemplo funcional: [Ejemplo](https://paiza.io/projects/Ty1lPcn8llIonIp1widIRg)